# How to pass a variable from a function in the component in Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

How to pass a variable from a function in the component in Vue?
 This is my code:

```
 export default {
    name: 'app',
      data: function () {
        return{
          city1: '',
          city2: '',
          metr: 0
        }
      },
      created () {
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init() {
        $data.city1 = 'sdf'; // ?this to data of component?
```

Comment: maybe `this.city1 = 'sdf'`.

Comment: no, it isn't work. I replace `function init()` to methods and there `this.city1 = 'sdf'` is work. I saw someone do like this: `$data.city1` but i can't to remember what exactly it was

Comment: david is right. The correct way to access or set variables in Vue is via direct access as `this.field` (in your case this.city1). You can reference the data as `this.$options.data` too .. buy why would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you created an new function, the `this` inside it will be not point to the Vue component, but to the `this` of the function itself.

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or save the reference of the `this`, then use it later.

```
created() {
  const self = this;

  ymaps.init(init);

  function init() {
    self.city1 = 'sdf';
  }
}
```

Or (better):

```
created() {
  const init = () => {
    this.city1 = 'sdf';
  }

  ymaps.init(init);
}
```